# Fetching photos in which 2 or more people are tagged

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photo-tagging

As the title says, I'm trying to fetch up to 10 photos in which the currently logged user and one or more of his/her friends are tagged. Currently I'm trying to do this with the PHP API and FQL.

I'm new to FQL, but not new to programming etc. The only way I am currently able to achieve what I want is by dynamically building multiple queries which look like this:

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN(  
  SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me() 
) AND pid IN( 
  SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE 
    subject = '1530195' OR 
    subject = '3612831' OR 
    subject = '6912041' OR 
    ...
)
```

Apart from being ugly, this is slow. Queries are limited to about the length shown above because they fail when they get much longer.

Multi-queries didn't help me because I can't use 'as', but SQL isn't my greatest strength and I'm really hoping I've missed something..

There must be a better way! Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two queries and do the intersection in your programming language of choice.

- `SELECT subject, pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()`
- `SELECT pid, subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

Batch these two calls

```
fql?q={"userphotos":"SELECT subject, pid 
                     FROM photo_tag 
                     WHERE subject = me()",
       "friendphotos":"SELECT pid, subject 
                       FROM photo_tag 
                       WHERE subject IN 
                      (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"}
```

Then in your programming language do an intersection of these two sets.

`a0 = data['data'][0]['fql_result_set']`
`a1 = data['data'][1]['fql_result_set']`

For example in Python, something simple as

```
>>> photos = {}
>>> for p in a0:
...     for q in a1:
...         if p['pid'] == q['pid']:
...             pid =  p['pid']
...             if pid in photos:
...                 photos[pid].append(p['subject'])
...             else:
...                 photos[pid] = [q['subject']]
...                 photos[pid].append(p['subject'])
```

photos will give a dict with each key having a list of ids as a value.
The just take 10 of these and supply it to the `photo` table FQL call

In Python with the `facepy` module it might look something like

```
photoquery = 'SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE '+
             'pid ='+pid1+' OR
             'pid ='+pid2+' OR
              ...

graph.fql(photoquery)
```

The slowest section overall will be the photo_tag query on friends.
`SELECT pid, subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

Comment: Thanks. This very nearly works, but the strange thing is that when I do `SELECT subject, pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()` as part of a multiquery it returns a lot of pictures of my friends, but not me. But when I issue exactly the same FQL request as a single query, it does what it should, and returns pictures of me.

The end result of this, when combined with the rest of your (very nice) logic is that I do indeed get pictures where 2 people are tagged, but I'm not one of them..

Comment: @MikeTimberlake could you pastebin 1) a snippet of each dataset in the multiquery response 2) your implementation of the logic. It would be rather strange if a query doesn't return what was requested, specifically `subject=me`

Comment: [see here](http://pastebin.com/eaiRygeM)

I hope that's clear enough? Maybe I'm doing the multiquery wrongly?

Comment: @MikeTimberlake All this means is `$multi_result[0]['fql_result_set'];` is actually friend data set and `$multi_result[`]['fql_result_set'];` is user data set. Easily verifiable by checking the name of the data set. `$multi_result[0]['name'];`

Comment: Yikes, am I really that stupid!? :( Thanks again for your help. I can't work on or verify this stuff today, but I'll report back tomorrow, with luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will improve performance.. But at the very least, it might make your query more readable:

You could use the familiar `WHERE IN (...)` statement instead of your `OR xxx OR yyy` format for the list of user ids...

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN( 
  SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me() 
) AND pid IN(
  SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN(
    '1530195', 
    '3612831',
    '36800240',
    ...
  )
```

These kinds of queries that involve the entire list of a users friends tend to be problematic for a number of reasons. Firstly there is possibly hundreds of friends so even if you manage to speed up performance for one query, you're going to have to execute a series of queries to iterate through the entire friend list of a user. Secondly, running these kinds of intensive queries one after the other on the API might trigger some throttling of your application...

The only thing I can suggest to you is to let your users know that you are performing an intensive operation and "it might take a moment" :P  Be hind the scenes you'll have to execute the queries and even possibly place a limit on each query as to not trigger some mechanisms on Facebook's side that might limit your access to the API.

Another option (that might need a little change to your applications flow) is instead of selecting ALL the users friends, display a list of the users friends and let them decide which friends they want to scan for mutual photos. This might also allow you to limit the actual amount of queries.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's very valuable for me that you've confirmed that I haven't simply missed the obvious way of doing this, as it took me a long time to accept that the API of a $100 billion website could be so weak.

The code I showed is never written, just created programmatically, and I wrote it like that to make the query as short as possible to avoid maximum string length problems. 

Looks like I might have to give up on this one. Although I only need a maximum of 10 images, so can break when done, it's still too slow and FB might not like it..